# Does any one know how I can add people into groups in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In django-admin I'm given a table with a list of people in it. The fields are for example:

```
firstname lastname occupation group
```

the first three columns are filled out already but the fourth (group) has to be done by me.

I would like to write an action that groups people into groups of say (3)

so the result would be

```
firstname lastname occupation group
mike      jones    doctor     1
tracy     jackson  laywer     1
Mack      Bean     Actor      1
Steward   Griffin  Baby       2
Candice   Green    Cashier    2
```

Anyone know how I can do this? I didnt add code because I dont know where to start

Comment: are the records already there in table or you want to group it whenever the record is added..?

Comment: the records would already be there, however if its easier to answer with the records not being there, I'll take it

Comment: You want to actually add people to a group, then have the group show up in the change list - or just group records by threes? Its not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
maxId = People.objects.all().aggregate(MAX('id'))['id__max']  

newgroupid = maxId / 3

if maxId % 3 == 0:
    newgroupid = newgroupid
else:
    newgroupid = newgroupid + 1
```

now use this newgroupid to insert the record.